# MySQL - COUNT for rows with the same name

Tags: sql, count, distinct, warehouse

I want to count how many entries with the same name from my table device [device.name] have the value 2 as warehouse [device.warehouse_id].

So for example I have 5 rows, 2 with name = Beam, 2 with name = Spot and 1 with name = Strobe.

---

And now I want the result from the select to be:

2 Beam

2 Spot

1 Strobe

(want to know the stock of every device)

---

I know it has to be something with
"`SELECT COUNT(device.name) FROM device WHERE device.warehouse_id = '2'`

That would work, and the COUNT itself works too, but I want to count every "set" of names.

Of course I could do an UNION and write the same query for each device.name, but I want to know how I can do it for all existing names at once, without to write them down.

---

I hope you know what I mean and what I want.

Thanks, Fabio

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*), device.name
FROM device 
WHERE 
  device.warehouse_id = '2' 
GROUP BY 
  device.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT device.name, COUNT(device.name) AS count 
FROM device 
GROUP BY device.name;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).